# how to incorporate tooltip function in react js

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to incorporate a tooltip into React Js. However I'm not sure how to incorporate the $(function), even adding this to index.html doesn't make it work.

```
// where do I put this??
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

render() {
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
     Tooltip on top
  </button>
}
```

Comment: Create a helper function and call that helper function in componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Comment: Just want to note that it's not really good practice to manipulate DOM in React. You should have a tooltip component that you show/hide based on some state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in ComponentDidMount which will be called immediately after your component mounted to the DOM.

```
  ComponentDidMount(){
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    }
```

Comment: i get an error "'$' is not defined no-undef " using this method

Comment: You need to add jquery into your project. you can either add `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` this jQuery CDN to your index.html or you can add a npm package of jquery and import in to your js file